# How to add an attribute on load time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a html page in which i have a number of anchor tags i want to add rel="no follow" attribute in anchor tag if it doesn't  have it on the pages whose source is starting with hyper text transfer protocol request. some of the anchor have already rel attribute. how can i achieve it through

example:-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p> Here we go</p>
        <a href="https://www.abc.com"> a1</a>
        <a href="https://www.abc.com" rel="nofollow" > a2</a>
        <a href="https://www.abc.com">a3</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want to add rel= no follow attribute  on a1 and a2 on page load time how can i achieve this

Comment: `rel="nofollow"` you are missing quotes .

Comment: Should the src actually be an href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tri this:

```
var A=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i< A.length;i++)
{
    if(A[i]['rel']!="")
    {
        A[i].setAttribute("rel","Something");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').each(function(){
    if(this.innerHTML == 'a1' || this.innerHTML == 'a2'){
        $(this).attr('rel','nofollow');
    }
});
```

**updated after op's cpmment**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cswRd/)

```
$('a[href^="http"]').attr('rel', 'nofollow'); // all links starting with http wil get rel attribute
```

[**^ attribute starts with selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Change you HTML

```
<a src="https://www.abc.com"> a1</a>
```

to

```
<a href="https://www.abc.com"> a1</a>
```

it's not `src` it's `href`

Comment: i don't want to apply this condition using inner html i want to check it if a contains rel then add rel else do nothing

Comment: +1, nice Tushar, didn't know about those special attribute selectors.

Comment: @BrianWigginton good :) Happy that you learned something from my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a:contains('a1'),a:contains('a2')").attr("rel","no follow");
```

reference [contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

**updated**

```
if($("a").attr("rel")=="no follow")
 {
// do stuff
  } else{// if not exist
  //do your stuff
  }
```

Comment: i don't want to apply this condition using inner html i want to check it if a contains rel then add rel else do nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {// on page load time
  $('a').each(function () {// check every a element
    var text = $(this).html();// get the content
    if (text.indexOf('a1') > 0 || text.indexOf('a2') > 0) {// find a1 and a2
      $(this).attr('rel', 'no follow');// set the rel to no follow
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Code**

```
$('a:not([rel])[href^="http"]').attr('rel','nofollow')
```

Tushar Gupta provided a one liner that would find all http links and add `rel` attributes, however it didn't account for links that already had `rel` attributes.

**Original Solution**

```
// find all links that do not have a rel attribute
$('a:not([rel])').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        href = $this.attr('href');

    // check that the link starts with http[s]://
    if(href && href.match(/https?:\/\//)) {
        $this.attr('rel', 'nofollow');
    }
});
```